# useAutocomplete Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I have a problem with my autocomplete textfield. I am trying to load all Users into a var called "Mitarbeiter". As you see in the code below:

```
var mitarbeiter;
db.collection("Mitarbeiter").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            mitarbeiter = [doc.id,doc.data()]
            console.log("MITARBEITER ",mitarbeiter);
        });
    });
```

This step is working fine. Now I am trying to load all of them into a AutoComplete textare:

```
<Autocomplete
id="combo-box-demo"
options={mitarbeiter}
onChange={e => setMit(e.target.value)}
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
style={{ width: 350 }}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Mitarbeiter" variant="outlined" />}
                    />
```

But the error shows:

> useAutocomplete  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Where is my mistake?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to console log the array you are passing to `Autocomplete`?

Comment: yes its working fine

Comment: The first chunk of code is in the front end or backend? because I'm seeing like you are querying a db.

Comment: It shows empty outsite my db.collection call. But why?

Comment: Thats an `async` call, but again the first code snippet is in the front or backend?

Comment: its frontend. How would you call the db with an async call?